# Getting an error running a C# script using a NuGet package; I think the NuGet package is running under an old version of .NET

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, roslyn

I am using the 0Zero.Sandbox library from NuGet to sandbox a C# script, but I'm getting this error when I define an expression-bodied method:

> Error (CS1002): ; expected

And here is my function:

```
public T Evaluate<T>(string code)
{
    var str =
$@"using System;
namespace MyScripts
{{
    public static class Script
    {{
        public static {typeof(T)} Function() => {code};
    }}
}}";
    new SandBoxer(str, false).SandBox.Call("MyScripts.Script", "Function", out T result);
    return result;
}
```

I think what's happening is the NuGet package is running under an old version of .NET that doesn't support expression bodied methods, but I don't know how to force it to run under the latest version like my actual project. How would I do that? If I replace the expression bodied method with a regular method:

```
public static {typeof(T)} Function() {{ return {code}; }}
```

it runs just fine... Or am I just missing an obvious syntax error? I don't think that's the case though because I can compile my function just fine using Roslyn without getting any errors...

Comment: I don't think that typeof(T) is stringified as you expect. I'd try with `typeof(T).Name` in the string, or another method declaration such as `public static Function<T>() { return (T)code `.

Comment: `typeof(T)` is being stringified as `System.Int32` when I pass in `int` for the `T` type parameter. If I replace the expression bodied function with a regular function, it works, so that can't be the problem.

Comment: Its author does not even associate the source code somewhere with this package, so your assumption of "it was just a wrapper around Roslyn" comes from the middle of nowhere, and should be incorrect. Its history on NuGet.org https://www.nuget.org/packages/0Zero.SandBox/ shows it might be created in 2015, while Roslyn was open sourced in 2014, https://corefx.lextudio.com/, so it might be based on CodeDOM which is very old, and does not support any new C# syntax. You can decompile its assemblies to see what exactly it uses to process C# source code though.

Answer (score 0):

The library running under whatever version of .net your application is targeting.  It may be only able to parse an older [version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29#Versions) of the C# language though.  The framework version and C# language version are not tied together, they can and do evolve separately.

If that's the case, the library would have to be updated to be able to parse a newer version.  The package seems like it was last updated after C# 6.0 was released, so that would be the last version of the language it could understand, if it was ever updated to do so.

Comment: I wonder why the library is even trying to parse C# code though - I thought it was just a wrapper around Roslyn...

Comment: @ekolis could be looking at a specific version of roslyn, you'd have to check the source.